# Importing Contributions

Tags: civicontribute, import

I am currently trying to import contributions to CiviCRM, and it will not let me. Ill get all the way to the import option, it will tell me that all rows are valid, then once I import, all rows are invalid. It is saying that my contact id is not valid, but it is! I have exhausted everything in my ability, and as wondering if you could help me out.

Thanks,

Chandler

Comment: Are you trying to import contributions to specific contacts already in your civicrm database, or are you attempting to add contacts as well? What exact error message are you getting? I'm not sure of the answer, but the more specific details the better.

Comment: What option did you selected for import mode at the time of import contribution?

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you check the detailed error message (you can download a csv file which contains those).

Maybe CiviCRM thinks that some columns are the contribution_id and it automatically selects this column to be matched with contribution_id. Then when doing this, it cannot find this ID.

I have expirienced exactly this problem, ignoring that column during import helped.